# How can I see the layout structure of Status-bar, Navigation bar and System keyboard in Android?

Tags: android, layout, view, ddms, system-views

I am using Dump View Hierarchy for UI Automator to see the layout structure for Android app. (Dump View Hierarchy for UI Automator image below)
 [image: Dump View Hierarchy for UI Automator]

You can see this option by selecting the DDMS.
But this tool is not showing the layout structre of Status-bar, Navigation bar and System keyboard.
How can I see the layout of Status-bar, Navigation bar and System keyboard?

Comment: Since those are not rendered by your activity, but instead are outside of your process, I am not aware that you can use normal SDK tools to examine them.

Comment: i'm not sure i compeletly understand your question, but you can see all the layout structure in your phone by enabling `Developer Options` and the enable `Show layout bounds`.